# SVN "Not authorized to open root of edit operation" for some users

Tags: svn

We have seven users on SVN, everybody has wide open access to the repository.  Yesterday two of the seven users started receiving the message "Not authorized to open root of edit operation."  I added what seems to be the usual answer to the end of authz:

```
[/]
* = r
```

But that did nothing to change the situation.

Answer (score 0):

As is often times the case I find the answer mere minutes after posting the question.  Those two users were using http:// instead of https://.  I had made some adjustments on the server yesterday.  Thinking back to what changes I made led me to the source of the problem.

Thanks for stopping by and reading!